# How to tell that projector needs bulb replacement?

Tags: home-theater, projector

I have an NEC projector which I estimate to have been used pretty close to the 2000-2500 hours, which is approximately the lifetime of a bulb.

As of late, light dots are beginning to appear on the projection in increasing numbers.  First there were 3-4, now about two dozen.  It kind of looks like a celestial constellation.

Is this is a sign that I need a bulb replacement or could it be a different problem?

Comment: sounds like dead pixels, which means it's not the light but the reflector chip that's going dead.

Comment: can that be easily replaced?

Comment: That pretty much totals any projector. Cleaning the lens once on mine, capillary action got alcohol on the inside of the lens and made some spots when it dried; noticeable only to myself. Failed pixels should be fairly easy to tell the difference. Sitting under it when the light blew out was startling, however no damage resulted like they always warn you about.

Comment: i have a hard time accepting the above comment

Comment: Search Youtube or similar for 'stuck pixel fixer'.  It's effectively patterns of pure red/green/blue, cycling the pixels to try to unstick them.  I've success with reducing problems in panels, but I've never tried them on a projector.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about home improvement.

Comment: why is there a home theater tag then?

Comment: @Joe The pixels are not stuck. It's not an LCD. It's a DLP projector and these are dead mirrors on his DMD :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell when the lamp dies by measuring the foot lamberts of light from a calibration image when new. I presume you don't have this reference level so, really, the lamp should be replaced when you feel like it's affecting picture quality.

Your situation sounds like something more sinister like chip or DMD death.

Comment: do you think it can be replaced or is the projector totaled?

Comment: It depends on the projector. You may be able to replace it or it may be under extended warranty.

Comment: this is what i found:  http://www.globalprojectors.com/nec-np215-new-original-dmd-chip.html

Comment: @amphibient $200 chip +$200 blub? Projectors are way down in price... namely because 50" LCD's blow them away in picture quality and cost less.

Comment: but not in picture size...  mine projects 98" over a 16' distance.  also, we established i don't need a new bulb, just a chip

Comment: @amphibient yours is a DLP projector, then. This part may be user-servicable but be very careful working around the light engine.